# api for within distance polygon

Tags: java, oracle

Is there any API to obtain a list of vehicle within a certain distance (Eg:10 KM)? I am using the map from geoserver. And need to draw the circle within that distance.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look [here](http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html) to see how you can obtain the distance between 2 GPS points (1 point being the vehicle you want to track and the other being the centre of the circle). Once that you have obtained the distance, check to see if the distance is greater than the radius. If the distance is less than the radius, the vehicle is in the circle. If it is equal to the radius, the vehicle is on the edge of the circle, if it is greater than the radius, then, the vehicle is outside the circle.

If you need more complex calcualtions, you might want to take a look at [Spheres](http://geospatialmethods.org/spheres/):

> A Java package for doing spherical trigonometry without all the messy
>   (and cpu intensive) trigonometry. The spheres package includes classes
>   for points, spherical polygons, latitude/longitude bounding boxes,
>   orbits, and scenes.

Comment: the point on the map we can call location point, and location point is the center of the circle

Comment: @Kandhi: Yes, the centre of the circle is one of the points, the other is the vehicle you want to check. You will have to iterate through your vehicle's locations and check each one.

Comment: I know the bounding box, but Need to draw the circle .any API is there?

Comment: @Kandhi: If you want to actually draw the circle, I would assume that it depends on with what are you actually working. Is it Swing, a web application, etc?

Comment: @Kandhi: So you want to draw a circle around all your vehicles?

Comment: no,want to draw the area within a certain distance from the location point